# Need to replace characters in a data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

i have a data frame that i need to visualize in R Studio, and for two columns of info (that show the names of points of origin and destination) some of the characters are like this:

```
St.P<U+00BA>lten
```

This happens for different words like

```
W<U+00BA>rgl, V<U+00BA>cklabruck
```

this happens only in those two columns of the data frame,

How do i remove those letters, or replace them? i feel like it needs to search those particular strings

```
<U+00BA>
```

in the two columns and replace them whenever it finds them, do u guys know some code that will help me achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not so clear on what you're asking. Can you provide an example of what it looks like now and how you would like it to be transformed?

Comment: Edited so as to show the problem, which looks like a unicode encoding issue on your machine.

Comment: `x <- gsub("<U+00BA>", "", x)`?

Comment: @RyanMorton Or possibly `x <- gsub("<U+00BA>", "o", x)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are showing us the display with some other program than R. If you look at `?Syntax` at the R console you will see that Unicode characters are quoted after an escaped-u, e.g. `"\u00BA"`. That character isn't really an umlauted-lowercase-o, but perhaps the authors of that data source are using a different character set. So you could match that oddball spelling of `Vöcklabruck"` with this regex logical test

```
 grepl( "V\\u00BAcklabruck" , R_reference_to_your_column)
```

That should be `TRUE` for all of the examples you mentioned.

A "real" lowercase umlaut-o in your source's notation is  and in R's notation `"\u00E4", so I suspect you actually want to do this:

```
  your_dfrm$yourcol <- gsub( "\\u00BA", "\u00E4", your_dfrm$yourcol)
```

Most systems these days are set up to display "umlauted characters", i.e. ones with a vowel that have a diaresis.

Answer (score 0):

If I treat the text in your question as the literal content of your strings, I can turn them back into Unicode characters using:

```
library(stringr)
x = c("W<U+00BA>rgl", "V<U+00BA>cklabruck")
unicode_chars = str_match(x, "<U\\+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>")
str_replace(x, "<U\\+[a-zA-Z0-9]+>", paste0("\\u", unicode_chars[, 2]))
# Output:
[1] "Wºrgl"       "Vºcklabruck"
```

But maybe your strings are already stored as Unicode and it's a problem with how your system displays them, in which case this won't help.